# How to include php file between two shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, shortcode

i want to include another php file "1.php" in my php file "my.php" between two shortcode [restrict] and [/restrict].

I try this codes but the answer did not work

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode( '[restrict]' . include '1.php' . '[/restrict]' ); ?>
```

Plese

Comment: This is really a duplicate of the linked question. You cannot have an `include` in an `echo`. The solution is to do something like MacPrawn suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the output buffer functions:

```
ob_start
include('1.php');
$file_content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo do_shortcode( '[restrict]' . $file_content . '[/restrict]' );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me!

Comment: Maybe the problem is the shortcode used?

Comment: Hmmm, well - what is the shortcode supposed to do? If you try it with some hard-coded content instead of the included file, does it work as expected?